# R text message output dependent on keystroke entered

Tags: r, interactive

I have two text messages and a question.

```
text1 <- "that is correct"

text2 <- "that is incorrect"

print("Question: Is 2+2=4 ?")
```

I would like the text message of `text1` to print out if I press the Y key and the text message of `text2` to print out if I press the N key.

How am I able to do this in R?

Comment: You might need `?readline`. For example try something like `switch(readline("Question: Is 2 + 2 = 4?\n"), "Y" = text1, "N" = text2)`

Comment: Thanks that is great.